# How to fix message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0" for resposive google adsense?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, adsense, screen-size

I am currently using responsive layout and there are two adsense units that one of them will display on the user's screen depending on the screen size, the code looks like this:

```
<div id="ad_right" class="d-none d-md-inline">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block; margin-left:20px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-rightslot" data-ad-slot="rightslot" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>

<div id="ad_bottom" class="d-md-none">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-bottomslot" data-ad-slot="bottomslot" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

As you see, the right ads shows if users have screen that matches a PC size(md or larger), and the bottom ads shows if users have mobile/tablet screen(xs or sm). The issue is that, the elements are hidden but the script always runs, thus the code runs twice:

```
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Leading to the error message for google adsense. How do I fix this problem? I tried everything I could and aint able to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense skips ad slots which are hidden: if ins tag has `display: none` - it won't be processed. At the moment it doesn't check parents, like if parent has `display: none` - it's not considered hidden even though ad slot is not visible. So try applying styles on the  element itself when hiding it.

Comment: What do you mean by applying styles on the element when hiding it? What I did was to have separate script tags that should execute if the parent element is not hidden(and apparently, the script both execute even if the parent element is hidden, leading to this error message). Do you have a working example?

Comment: How are those elements hidden? Using CSS that you wrote or by some library CSS? My point is that if <ins> element has `display: none` applied to it directly, e.g. using `.adsbygoogle { display: none; }` then adsense will skip that slot

Comment: For me, as of 2024, adding `display: none` does not resolve this issue.